# How do I configure a valid TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12 build definition?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to setup a solution in Visual Studio Online to deploy to an Azure website. I've configured the website in Azure, downloaded the subscription file, and I'm now trying to figure out how to configure the build definition.

Most of this screen seems straightforward, but the Section 2.3 (Configurations) option (where I've selected the `Release|Any CPU` config) has an error glyph with the error:

```
Parameter 2. Configurations: cannot convert value 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.PlatformConfigurationList' of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.PlatformConfigurationList to type System.String[], reset to default.
```

Any idea what this means or how I can fix it?

Comment: Not an answer to your issue, but is there a reason you're not using the source control integration you get when setting up the Azure website?  If it's a TFS-based repository, you'll end up having the build created for you and then you can edit it (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-continuous-delivery-use-vso) and if it's a git based repo, it will use kudu for the deployment and you won't need to worry about a build at all.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I have configured the Source Control Integration on the website, but I was under the impression that that just allowed VSO _into_ Azure so that it could deploy - I assumed I still needed to get VSO to actually push the site. Anyway, when I queue a build in VSO it builds fine but doesn't deploy, so I'm trying to understand the options available. I had actually set this project up more than a year ago as an experiment with Azure and was able to deploy the site just fine. Now I'm revisiting it in VS2013 I'm not having such luck.

Comment: check out the link the previous comment - it does a pretty good walk through of the process - by default it should set up a CI build that will deploy to Azure whenever changes are commited and you shouldn't need to queue any builds - although, you should be able to do without any issues.

Comment: If you're starting over, and you're open to using git for source control, it's a great experience in my opinion. You can make a new VSO team project and select git.  I won't get into the advantages of it over TFS for source control, but for deploying an Azure website it's much more straightforward - there are essentially no builds - it uses Kudu, a deployment engine that lives with your Azure site to do a very quick deployment whenever the relevant branch in the repository is updated.  I would recommend this over TFS if it's an option for you.

Comment: OK, so I had in fact followed the tutorial you linked, but it didn't seem to change the existing build definition (which was the old AzureContinuousIntegration.11 template). I deleted the build definition, disconnected/reconnected source control integration in Azure, and then opened the solution again (from the Visual Studio link in Azure), and now I see a newly-created build definition. I then triggered a build manually, and now it's not even compiling (Could not find a part of the path 'd:\a\bin\_PublishedWebsites'. (type DirectoryNotFoundException))

Comment: I'm actually open to starting again with git - but it bugs me that I don't seem to be really understanding what's going on with TFS (especially when I had it working originally)...

Comment: I agree- it's disconcerting that something that should be wired up and working automatically isn't working at all...If you right click and publish the web application from VS directly, does it compile and make it to Azure successfully?

Comment: Yep - it builds and deploys just fine from VS2013 on my laptop. Very annoying.